# Print file contents opened with fopen in GDB?

Tags: c, gdb, fopen

I am attempting to print the contents of a file opened with fopen in C within GDB.

For example, take the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r");
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to be able to view the contents of this file when running the compiled executable in GDB. Thankyou!

Comment: What have you tried? How did that work? How didn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am attempting to print the contents of a file opened with fopen in C within GDB.

You need to have `libc` which is compiled with debug info. For example, on Linux, using GLIBC and with `libc6-dbg` installed, using your example program, modified to actually read the file (merely `fopen`ing and immediately `fclose`ing the file doesn't read *anything*):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r");
    int ch = fgetc(file);              /* force a read */
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x115d: file t.c, line 6.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:6
6           file = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r");
(gdb) n
7           int ch = fgetc(file);
(gdb) n
8           fclose(file);
(gdb) p *file
$1 = {_flags = -72539000, _IO_read_ptr = 0x555555559481 "oot:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"..., _IO_read_end = 0x55555555a1c6 "", ..., _IO_read_base = 0x555555559480 "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"...
```

Here you can see that the data which will be returned by subsequent reads is pointed to by `file->_IO_read_ptr`, and the entire buffer is pointed by `file->_IO_read_base`.

The members will depend on which `libc` you use, and the amount of buffered data (if any) will depend on buffering that the stream was opened with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *call function*.  You write a function that prints the contents of a file as you wish and you call it from gdb.

```
(gdb) help call
Call a function in the program.
Usage: call EXP
```

> The argument is the function name and arguments, in the notation of
> the current working language.  The result is printed and saved in the
> value history, if it is not void.

Of course, in that function you should preserve the file position -- *ftell* at the beginning, *fseek* at the end, etc.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void
debug_file(FILE*f)
{
   printf("keep ftell, read, print, restore position\n");
}

int main() { 
    ....
}

% gcc -O0 -g3 gbd.c
% gdb ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x118f: file gbd.c, line 12.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /work/stub/a.out

Breakpoint 1, main () at gbd.c:12
12          file = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r");
(gdb) n
13          int ch = fgetc(file);              /* force a read */
(gdb)
14          fclose(file);
(gdb) call debug_file(file)
keep ftell, read, print, restore position
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[Inferior 1 (process 6432) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @EmployedRussian It is a common method in C programming, however.  Of course, not especially to print the contents of a file, but to print different internals.   But yes, if you cut *at all* from your statement, it may be true.

Comment: @alinsoar could you provide an example in gdb with the same/similar code as what I have provided?